# Convert JavaScript object to JSON and POST it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have to parse my html from and POST it to another script. When I use `JSON.stringify` to serialize object with parsed data, $_POST array in the receiving script is empty:

```
$("#addQueryForm").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  result = {}     
  result['kindArr'];
  result['factor'];
  $("[rel=my-form]").each(function() {
    result[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).attr("value");
  }); 
  var form = JSON.stringify(result);    
  $.post("add_kind.php", form , function(data) {
    alert(data);  
    //data shows me that $_POST array is empty
  }); 
});
```

But if I write json string into the query manually, it would be correct:

```
$.post("add_kind.php", {"kind":"Var1","kindArr":"Var12345","factor":"Var0","synonym1":"Var1","synonym2":"Var2","synonym3":"Var3"} , function(data) {
    alert(data);  
    //data shows me that $_POST contains posted data
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S: `stringify` was excess.

Comment: you can use $('#form').serialize()

Comment: Your second version isn't a JSON string, it's a Javascript object. jQuery converts it to www-form-urlencoded format, not JSON.

Comment: You don't need to stringify the result, jQuery handles everything correctly for you. So handing in `result` should work just fine. However, strings work too, so there might be something wrong how you build it. Does `("[rel=my-form]")` yield the desired result-set?

Comment: @Christoph yes, all data is correct, but when I send them with var, something goes wrong.

Comment: @Barmar yes, it was my mistake. You're right. Thanks! Without `stringify` it works. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) would be better in your situation:

```
var form = $(this).serialize();    
$.post("add_kind.php", form, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: No, I append some inputs after page loads and `form = $(this).serialize(); ` cannot get them, isn't it?

Comment: If they are part of your form - serialize will get them too.